# GeneXus Server: The file exists

Tags: genexus

Using Genexus 17 U6.
Suddenly, today all the KBs we have in Genexus Server local installation stoped to update or commit. Sometimes, restarting the gx server database it is possible to lock some objects for a few minutes.
I'm able to access the GX Server web application and create/delete versions, for example, but in Genexus the commit and update are generation the error below:

```
========== Receive changes started ==========
Contacting GeneXus Server at 'https://10.120.0.11/genexusserver17'... 
GeneXus Server: Update since 6/27/2023 6:32:57 PM requested by local\my-user on version KB_my-kb of 'KB_my-kb'
error: GeneXus Server: The file exists.

Failed: Receive changes
```

Have somebody already struggled this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Following the page https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?9562,GeneXus+Server+Common+Issues I recreated the folder C:\Windows\Temp and Gx Server started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on the gxserver trace and let's see if any clue appears on the log/trace file.

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwwiki/servlet/wiki?10948,Tracing+GeneXus+Server

Probably you will need to delete temporary files form you server.